# What modification is this of the notion of Renyi divergence?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, information-theory, information-geometry

Given two probability distributions $P$ and $Q$ over the same outcome and event space (assume finite if needed) one defines their Renyi divergence as $D_\alpha (P \vert \vert Q) = \frac{1}{\alpha -1} \log \left (  \sum _{x \in \Omega} P^{\alpha} (x) Q^{1-\alpha}(x) \right ) $

Now I see the following equations related to this which I am totally unable to parse,

- $D(P_{Y \vert X} \vert \vert Q_{Y \vert X } \vert  P_X ) = D(P_{Y\vert X} P_X \vert \vert Q_{Y \vert X} P_X )$
- $H(X) - H(X \vert Y) = D(P_{Y \vert X} \vert \vert P_Y \vert P_X ) = D( P_{Y \vert X} P_X \vert \vert P_Y \times P_X)$
- $D(P_{Y \vert X} \vert \vert Q_Y \vert P_X ) = {\mathbb E} [ D (P_{Y \vert X} (.\vert X ) \vert \vert Q_Y)]$

Can someone help understand these identities?

---

I am unable to locate any definition for any of these $4$ things,

$D(P_{Y \vert X} \vert \vert Q_{Y \vert X } \vert  P_X )$

$D(P_{Y\vert X} P_X \vert \vert Q_{Y \vert X} P_X )$

$D (P_{Y \vert X} (.\vert X ) \vert \vert Q_Y)$

$D( P_{Y \vert X} P_X \vert \vert P_Y \times P_X)$

Answer (score 2):

The [Renyi divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9nyi_entropy#R.C3.A9nyi_divergence) is a family of quantities of which the relative entropy $D(P\|Q)$ is a special case when $\alpha = 1$.

The identities you listed involve the entropy and relative entropy of random variables $X$ and $Y$.  For example, your first identity is:

\begin{align}
D(P_{Y \vert X} \vert \vert Q_{Y \vert X } \vert  P_X )
&= \sum_x P_X(x) \sum_y P_{Y|X}(y|x)\log \frac{P_{Y|X}(y|x)}{Q_{Y|X}(y|x)} \\
&= \sum_{x,y} P_{Y|X}(y|x) P_X(x)\log \frac{P_{Y|X}(y|x)P_X(x)}{Q_{Y|X}(y|x)P_X(x)} \\
&= D(P_{Y\vert X} P_X \vert \vert Q_{Y \vert X} P_X )
\end{align}

---

Update:

$Q_{Y|X}$ and $P_{Y|X}$ are conditional probability distributions.  $P_X$ is a probability distribution. Everything I wrote is just definition.

The identities you listed don't have anything to do with Renyi divergence, so they don't follow from its definition.

[Entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29) $H$ and [relative entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) $D$ are functions of probability distributions. 
$$H(P) = -\sum_x P(x)\log P(x)$$
$$D(P\|Q) = \sum_x P(x)\log\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$$

Comment: @b yen Can you kindly define this quantity "$Q_{Y\vert X}$" and ``$P_{Y \vert X }$" ? I am unable to see why even your first-line is true. Is that a definition? I can't see it to be following from the definition of Renyi divergence...

Comment: The identities you listed don't have anything to do with Renyi divergence. I'll write a little more explanation.

Comment: This isn't clear. $Q$ is a probability distribution on its own. So basically it is a random variable which is assigning a probability to every outcome in some space.  (though $Q$ is *not* a probability measure because on its own it doesn't know what the "events" are) So what is $Q_{Y \vert X}$?  What do $Y$ and $X$ have to be for this to make sense?

Comment: And what is the meaning of anything like $D(P \vert \vert Q \vert R)$ ?

Comment: In information theory, there are many ways to use these quantities. $X$ and $Y$ are commonly the inputs and outputs of communication channels, and $Q_{Y|X}$ and $P_{Y|X}$ can be interpreted as the "probability transition matrices" of two different channels. The definition of $D(P \vert \vert Q \vert R)$ is the first line of math I wrote above. It's the conditional relative entropy.  Relative entropy can be thought of as a measure of difference between two probability distributions (conditioned on $R$ in this case).

Comment: So are X and Y events from a common sigma-algebra on which these two probability distributions P and Q are defined?

Comment: So P and Q are to be thought of as maps assigning a probability to each of these outcomes? P : X x Y -> [0,1] and Q : X x Y -> [0,1] ? So what are the maps $P_X,P_Y, Q_X, Q_Y$ ?

Comment: I am not understanding your definiton. I think X and Y are events and then one should think of P and Q as being random variables mapping the outcomes to real numbers and then define it as, 

 D( P(Y|X) || Q(Y|X) | P_X) := \sum(x in X) P( x) \sum (y in Y) P( y )P( x) log[ ( P( y )P( x) )  / ( Q( y )Q(x) )]